# Unable to find entry at address in hyperleder sawtooth validator

Tags: javascript, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I have setup a `Hyperlder Sawtooth Network` from the `Sawtooth Docs`, you can find `docker-compose.yaml` I used to setup the network here:

https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.0/app_developers_guide/sawtooth-default.yaml

And here's the `transaction-processor` gist

https://gist.github.com/rohitkhatri/04bb90c531385d8825c5243773d6a269

Can find the validator log here:

https://justpaste.it/74y5g

Transaction processor log:

https://justpaste.it/5ayn6

I'm running a custom `transaction processor`, and what's happening is after some successful transactions, the batch status is stuck on `PENDING` and when I check the logs of `validator`, there's always a entry says this:

```
Unable to find entry at address 5f68a3afa88f4a92fc362957d4c87101c884c97f2fcf92acbd512a2d12ef9d5bee55ee
```

And in my `transaction processor`, I'm doing `console.log` so I can check whether the `validator` is calling the `apply` function of my processor, but I don't get any logs.

In brief, after some transactions, the validator is not calling the `apply` function of my `transaction processor`.

If anybody has faced this issue, please give a hand.

Comment: Provide more details about your setup. How many validators? Is it consistent after a certain amount of time your TP do not get the transactions anymore? Have you tried the 1.0.4 versions?

Comment: @FrankC. I have provided the `docker-compose.yaml` link and that's the exact setup I have, and the I have updated the question and attached a `gist` of the`transaction processor` that I have created.

Comment: Change the version on all the `hyperledger` images to 1.0.4. I assume you are constructing the Transaction correctly with at least `outputs` set to the address you are using in the `setState`. Also, please include the log that includes some of the preceding message before hitting the error above.

Comment: @FrankC. Sure, I will give it a try and let you know, thanks.

Comment: Hey @FrankC. the solution didn't work and I have updated the question and attached a link to the full log of the validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often if the transaction is stuck on PENDING, the Transaction Processor has not started or died.  Are you sure it is running?

More rarely, the validator failed the Z Test (z-teste
d out) because it was winning too frequently.

Comment: Yes, It was running and there was no error and was also connected to `validator`.